# openvpn with systemd: reconnect

Tags: systemd, openvpn

I'm using openvpn enabled as a service. It works well, but once I get assigned a new IP address or lose the connection, I can't access to the internet any more. Then I have to systemctl restart openvpn@ipredator.conf manually. How can I fix that so I don't have to login as root each time and restart the service manually?

```
[root@arch paul]# cat /etc/openvpn/ipredator.conf 
client
dev tun0
proto udp
remote pw.openvpn.ipredator.se 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/ipredator.auth
auth-retry nointeract

ca [inline]

tls-client
tls-auth [inline]
ns-cert-type server

keepalive 10 30
cipher AES-256-CBC
tls-cipher TLSv1:!ADH:!SSLv2:!NULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!LOW:!MEDIUM:@STRENGTH
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
tun-mtu 1500
mssfix
passtos
verb 3

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
###censored###
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>

<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
###censored###
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

Comment: This should already be happening with `keepalive 10 30`, which will expand to `ping 10` and `ping-restart 30` on your client and try to reconnect after 30 seconds when the connection is lost. But it might get overridden by a directive pushed from the server. Please also post the server config or the log output from the client to see if any directives are pushed. Look for a line like this: `PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,ping 10,ping-restart 60'`

Comment: I dont know if it is solved, i am having the same issue after upgraded to systemd..

Answer (score 0):

Either try adding this to your .ovpn config

```
server-poll-timeout 4
```

Reference: https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-client-vpn-tunnel-connectivity/

Or you can add a simple bash script to cron job that will automatically restart openvpn if connection is lost. The script might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Makes sure that openvpn service is running all times.
# Add this to a cronjob that will run every minute
set -o pipefail
if $(/sbin/ip add | grep tun | grep inet)
then
echo "OpenVPN service is already running"
else
systemctl restart openvpn@ipredator.conf
echo "Restarted OpenVPN service"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

On my system, the systemd profile sits at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-client@.service` and covers all @ client configurations.  In the `[Service]` section you can add:

```
Restart=on-failure 
RestartSec=10
```

...to have it restart the service (retry connection) when exited, with a 10-second delay to wait in this example.

Then run `systemctl daemon-reload` to refresh systemd with the changes.